# What is the difference between // and //= in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to change decimal numbers to binary numbers without using bin.
In the while loop I originally used "n // 2" instead of "n//=2"
and when I run the file the program stopped.
What is the difference??

```
n=int(input("Enter a number\n"))
res=""
while n >= 1:
    res = res + str(n % 2)
    n //= 2
print(int(res[::-1]))
```

Comment: `//=` is used for an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements); `//` is an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

Answer (score 3):

`n //= 2` is the same as `n = n // 2`.

The reason your program stopped when you used `n // 2` is you were never assigning anything back to `n`, so `n` would never become < 1 therefore you were stuck in the loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

n // 2 is just a operator, while the loop is considered the condition of the value n. n //2 wont make the original n change, so if the original n >= 1 it can escape, else it will be stuck forever